# Solve in $\mathbb{R}$ the following equation:

Tags: linear-algebra

$$(\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}-1})^\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}-1}=(1+\sqrt{x})^{1+\sqrt{x}}$$

My attempt:

$$\Leftrightarrow(\frac{1+\sqrt{x}}{x-1})^{\frac{1+\sqrt{x}}{x-1}}=(1+\sqrt{x})^{1+\sqrt{x}}$$

I tried writing $1+\sqrt{x}=t$, then $x=t^{2}-2t+1$ and $x-1=t^{2}-2t$

$$(\frac{t}{t^{2}-2t})^{\frac{t}{t^{2}-2t}}=t^{t}$$
$$\Leftrightarrow (\frac{1}{t-2})^{\frac{1}{t-2}}=t^{t}$$
$$\Leftrightarrow (\frac{1}{t-2})^{\frac{1}{t-2}}-t^{t}=0$$
And i got stuck here. Any help would be appreciated. I know that sometimes this type of exercises can be solved using the monotony of functions, but i don't think that is the case here. I tried with $0$ and $1$ but they aren't solutions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Observe that $x^x$ is strictly increasing for $x \ge 1$, and $1+\sqrt x \ge 1$.

Note also that for $x < 1$, $x^x < 1$ and for $x > 1$, $x^x > 1$.

Therefore if the equation holds, we must have $1 + \sqrt x = \dfrac 1{\sqrt x- 1}$,  which gives the unique solution $x=2$.

Comment: Thank you for the solution!